# Can this algorithm achieve eventual consistency?

Tags: computer-networks

There are $M$ interconnected nodes in a peer-to-peer network. Initially,
each node numbers itself with any integer from $1$ to $N$, $N \leq M$.

Each node counts the most occurrences of neighboring nodes, including
itself, and modifies its number to that value.  If all the numbers occur
equally, a non-self number is randomly selected and changed to that
number.  Each node notifies its neighbors when initialization is
complete or when the numbering is updated.

My question is this:

- Can this rule achieve final agreement on the numbering of all nodes?
- If so, what is the expected time to reach agreement?

Comment: So in each round, a node $x$ updates its value to $\text{argmax} \{ v(y) \mid y \in N[x] \}$ where $N[x]$ is the set of $x$'s neighbors including itself?

Comment: Is this coming from a homework assignment or take-home exam?

Comment: @PålGD Simply put, a node always makes its number consistent with the number of most of the surrounding nodes (including itself)

Comment: This algorithm may not terminate: take a cycle with an even number of nodes

Comment: @nirshahar  Notice " If all the numbers occur equally, a non-self number is randomly selected and changed to that number."
This causes the numbering to be unevenly distributed

Comment: The numbers wont occur equally. Each node has exactly 2 neighbors.

Comment: I find "counts the most occurrences of neighboring nodes" unclear.  Can you [edit] the question to state that part of the algorithm more clearly and precisely?  Perhaps pseudocode or mathematics would be helpful, such as Pål GD was trying to help with.